# cvLoadImage Returning NULL

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, eclipse-cdt, ubuntu-12.04

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04,32 bit platform with OpenCV Version 2.4.1 on eclipse ide. The cvLoadImage() function is returning me a NULL value even after putting the image in the current Location of the project where I have the cpp file.

```
#include "highgui.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  char image[80]="baboon.jpg";
  IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(image,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  cout<<img<<endl;
}
```

Following are my include file directory:

> -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include

and

Following are the library files:

> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so

My img value is always zero (NULL). I am not getting any compilation errors.I checked similar posts on the forum but none of them could solve my problem.I even tried with a PNG image but faced the same issue.Kindly let know if anyone faced a similar issue before.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose operator << is not defined for IplImage, which is the old C structure from OpenCV v1. Also, you would have a memory leak using IplImage if you dont release the memory explicitely. Use C++ interface, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to give a full path to your image file? If didn't, make sure the image file is in the folder with an executable file ( some IDEs have a separate folder for debug and for release ).

Comment: Thank you so much Fico.,When I put the image file in the debug folder with the exe file and gave full path in the cvLoadImage() function.It starts to work fine but I had worked with opencv before on the Windows platform and there I put the image file in the folder where I had the source file.Can you please tell me if this is a IDE specfic or OS specific issue? Moreover,does it mean everytime I should give full path of the image file?..Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to OpenCV, too, but I think that here cout'<<'img'<<'endl; you're printing the pointer's value, i.e. the address stored in "img". here's an example that I use, and it works:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat image; // new blank image
    image = imread("lena.bmp", 0);// reads the image file (I put the image in the same    project's directory).
    namedWindow("My Loaded Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// creates a window for display.
    imshow("Display window",image);// shows the image inside it.
    waitKey(0);// wait for a keystroke in the window (When you don't do this, the image disappears instantly).
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a quite recent version of OpenCV, I recommend you to use the newer C++ interface for image (cv::Mat) and reading functions.

Does the operator << is even available for IplImage? I dont think so, that's probably the cause of your compilation error.

With the new interface, your code will look like that:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/highgui/higui.hpp>

using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  const std::string imageName = "baboon.jpg";
  cv::Mat img = cv::imread(image,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  cout<<img<<endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Hi remi, I wasn't getting any compilation errors and img is just a pointer variable which holds the address,so it should print the address of the location.Now it seems to be working fine now.I still thank you for your attempt :)

Comment: I read "I'm getting a compilation error" instead of "not getting any" :) Still, you have a memory leak! And you could pass your image name as a command line argument (argv[1])

Comment: Ya Remi,I was so involved the null returning value that forget to take account of memory leak. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the program from directly within eclipse, the image should be located in the folder which has .cpp file.

But If you are executing the program from terminal, image file should be in the same folder with executable.

You can use direct path to solve conflict, too.

Comment: Thats what I did,When I put it in the cpp folder the program doesn't find the image but when i paste it in the debug folder then it runs fine!..I still don't understand why its happening..Do you have any clue?